# Java 8: Parallel FOR loop

Tags: java, for-loop, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

I have heard Java 8 provides a lot of utilities regarding concurrent computing. Therefore I am wondering what is the simplest way to parallelise the given for loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Set<Server> servers = getServers();
    Map<String, String> serverData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    for (Server server : servers)
    {
        String serverId = server.getIdentifier(); 
        String data = server.fetchData();

        serverData.put(serverId, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Read up on [streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), they're all the new rage.

Pay especially close attention to the bit about parallelism:

> "Processing elements with an explicit for-loop is inherently serial. Streams facilitate parallel execution by reframing the computation as a pipeline of aggregate operations, rather than as imperative operations on each individual element. All streams operations can execute either in serial or in parallel."

So to recap, there are no parallel for-loops, they're inherently serial. Streams however can do the job. Take a look at the following code:

```
    Set<Server> servers = getServers();
    Map<String, String> serverData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    servers.parallelStream().forEach((server) -> {
        serverData.put(server.getIdentifier(), server.fetchData());
    });
```

Comment: Note that parallel streams have an overhead: it doesn't always improve performance over a serial stream (or normal for each).

Comment: how does threads are handled using .parallelStream() ? Does it use any internal thread-pool ?

Comment: What if we have a million elements in servers? Will this create a million parallel streams?

Comment: @SonuMishra, No. Parallel streams attempt to make use of multiple cores on the processer.

Comment: i think you could make it even more clear that the callbacks to the forEach method can/will be called in parallel

Comment: Is there anything like `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` as in `Parallel.ForEach` in C#? It helps us limit the number of threads we want to run in parallel.

Comment: @shashwat: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802463/how-many-threads-are-spawned-in-parallelstream-in-java-8 help ?

Answer (score 25):

That would be using a `Stream`:

```
servers.parallelStream().forEach(server -> {
    serverData.put(server.getIdentifier(), server.fetchData());
});
```

I suspect a `Collector` can be used to greater effect here, since you use a concurrent collection.

Comment: Well, after your advise, I now can read lambda expressions as well as know some details of streams as well ;)

Answer (score 14):

More elegant or functional solution will be just using Collectors toMap or toConcurrentMap function, which avoid maintaining another stateful variable for ConcurrentHashMap, as following example:

```
final Set<Server> servers = getServers();
Map<String, String> serverData = servers.parallelStream().collect(
    toConcurrentMap(Server::getIdentifier, Server::fetchData));
```

Note: 
 1. Those functional interfaces (`Server::getIdentifier or Server::fetchData`) doesn't allow throw checked exception here,
 2. To get the full benefits of parallel stream, the number of servers would be large and there is no I/O involved, purely data processing in those functions(`getIdentifier, fetchData`)

Please refer to Collectors javadoc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap

Answer (score 7):

Simple example to copy'n'paste (the examples above use the class `Server` which is a custom class written by the OP):

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Item1");
list.add("Item2");
list.parallelStream().forEach((o) -> {
    System.out.print(o);
});
```

Console output. The order could possibly vary as everything executes in parallel:

```
Item1
Item2
```

The `.parallelStream()` method was introduced in `Java v8`. This example was tested with `JDK v1.8.0_181`.