# Async annotation not making asychromous call

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have around `400k` employee ids .I can pass 1 employee id at a time.

`saveInDatabase()` methods saves the object in a database table.I have marked this method as `Synchronize`

I have added `@EnableAsync` too. I am making the call below :-

```
apiCallAndSave.callApi(employeeList);

public void callApi(List<Long> employeeList) {

        // Do async calls and store futures in a List
        List<Future<ResponseEntity<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long id : employeeList) {
            futures.add(getEmployee(id));    
        }

         System.out.println( " in here ");
        // Then process list of future 
        for (Future<ResponseEntity<String>> future : futures) 
            try{ 
                saveInDatabase(future.get());
               }
               catch(Exception e){ 
           e.printStackTrace();             
              }

         } 
@Async
public Future<ResponseEntity<String>> getEmployee(long employeeId) {

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    // set up HTTP Basic Authentication Header
    requestHeaders.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
    //for test
    System.out.println( "thread is " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
    //same threadname everytime : thread is restartedMain



       String url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/" + employeeId;
       ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                String.class);
       return new AsyncResult<ResponseEntity<String>>(responseEntity);
   }
```

Comment: Async support is proxy based. It can only work if you can an Async method of a bean from another bean.

Comment: @JBNizet Ididn't get you sorry. So where should I make the adjustment?

Comment: If you call a method from another method of the same class, Async, Transactional and all the proxy-based annotations won't work. The Async method of bean B must be called from **another** bean A, where B is injected. What don't you understand in this explanation?