# Thread usage of Java Parallel Stream Reduce

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream

How does Java handle Threads using Java Parallel Streams with the reduce function. Does every accumulator get its own thread? And if so, how many are there at one point of the time, does it depend on the stream size or on the machine its running on. Also where is all of that handled and managed?

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802463/how-many-threads-are-spawned-in-parallelstream-in-java-8

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: That helped me out, thanks!