# Java Stream Parallel - how many threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

Data processing sometimes is faster when several threads are used. But how can I control (or even find out) the amount of threads being used in code snippets like

```
List<Object> something = ...
something.stream().parallel().forEach(...)
```

So far I have neither seen an option to control the amount of threads, nor a way to read how many threads are getting used. Not even the documentation I found mentions how the system might decide on the amount of threads internally.

How is the amount of threads determined or controlled?

Comment: Depends on the implementation.

Comment: Here is a really good answer, it even shows how to control the amount of threads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802737/4222206